# Laravel 5 Helper functions

Tags: laravel-5

Does anyone know where the source code is located for the built in Laravel 5 helper functions like view() and str_limit()? I am curious to see how they are doing things in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

view function is located under

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/source/illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
```

line number 585

content is as follows:

```
if ( ! function_exists('view'))
{
/**
 * Get the evaluated view contents for the given view.
 *
 * @param  string  $view
 * @param  array   $data
 * @param  array   $mergeData
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 */
function view($view = null, $data = array(), $mergeData = array())
{
    $factory = app('Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory');

    if (func_num_args() === 0)
    {
        return $factory;
    }

    return $factory->make($view, $data, $mergeData);
}
}
```

start using an IDE like Php storm and you can find all this functions with a single click